# FileReader API skips my method even though it is only 2.5 MB and using Chrome 57

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, filereader, fileapi

I just noticed that the `FileReader API` skips the `handleFiles(appCSV)` and returns `undefined` instead.

```
appDictionary = handleFiles(appCSV);
dbDictionary = handleFiles(dbCSV);
```

My `appCSV` file size is just `2584729 bytes` or only about `2.5 MB`. Is the issue due to that?

This is strange since I am already using `Chrome 57`.

Kindly help me investigate and provide solutions or workarounds. Thanks!

Body of the `handleFiles` function:

```
function handleFiles(files) {
    // Check for the various File API support.
    if (window.FileReader) {
        // FileReader are supported.
        getAsText(files[0]);
    } else {
        alert('FileReader are not supported in this browser.');
    }
}

function getAsText(fileToRead) {

    let reader = new FileReader();
    // Handle errors load
    reader.onload = loadHandler;
    reader.onerror = errorHandler;
    // Read file into memory as UTF-8      
    reader.readAsText(fileToRead);

}

function loadHandler(event) {
    let csv = event.target.result;
    processDataToDictionary(csv);
}

function errorHandler(evt) {
    if (evt.target.error.name == "NotReadableError") {

        alert("Cannot read file!");

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the body of this `handleFiles` function ? But as it is written, I can already make an educated guess that you are not waiting for the onload event of the FileReader, all its `readAs...` methods are asynchronous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Kaiido Hi, I've posted the body of the  `handleFiles` function. IT does not skip `dbDictionary = handleFiles(dbCSV);` though, only `appDictionary`. Kindly help me investigate.

Comment: So, `appDictionary` and `dbDictionary` are set to `undefined` when you do `= handleFiles(foo)` because `handleFiles` doesn't return anything. Now I'll guess that in `processDataToDictionary` you are setting `dbDictionary` to something. Anyway, don't use these `appDictionary` and `dbDictionary` variables after having called `handleFiles`, instead, wrap the following of the actions in a callback function, that will get executed e.g after `processDataToDictionary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have **resolved** my own issue. It was due to that the `onLoad` event of `FileReader API` is `asynchronous`.

So I've decided to put the `handleFiles()` function in the `onchange() property` the `input type = 'file'`.